# How to change this from "../ReportApi" automatically when I deployed?

Tags: asp.net-core, reporting-services, rdlc, syncfusion

I've made rdlc reports and view using Syncfusion report viewer and It runs successfully. But, when I deploy it in server then the report could't found. I have to change the path manually from here (the code I've attached)

```
</script>
<ej-script-manager></ej-script-manager>
```

Answer (score 0):

In our ASP.NET Core application we are getting the report path from wwwroot folder. So we are using the WebRootPath for getting the wwwroot folder path as shown in below code example. In production side we need to include the report path.

```
public void OnInitReportOptions(ReportViewerOptions reportOption)
        {
            string basePath = _hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath;
            FileStream inputStream = new FileStream(basePath + @"\ReportData\InvoiceTemplate.rdl", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
            reportOption.ReportModel.Stream = inputStream;
        }
```

Please consult the [help documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/visual-studio-publish-profiles?view=aspnetcore-2.2#include-files) for how include the files when publishing the ASP.NET Core application.